# Why the filter of previously calculated value is not working in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, filtering

I have the dataset contains the PropertyID as a main key. Some of Properties has several Units.
I created the Measure

```
NumberOfUnitInProperty = DISTINCTCOUNT(dataset[Unit])
```

and want to filter the Properties having multiple units.

But when I apply the filter there is no any results. On the unfiltered table there are a lot of rows match with this criterium.

Please advise

Comment: Please share a screen grab of the filter and visual being used.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is one table only then you will need to do something like:

```
NumberOfUnitInProperty = 
  var pID = SELECTEDVALUE(dataset[PropertyID])
  var result = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(dataset[Unit]), FILTER(ALL([dataset]), dataset[PropertyID] = pID))
  RETURN result
```